# Why do I get undefined when using this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const array1 = [2,5,10];
    
    const arr10 = function(arr) { arr.map(x => x * 10); };
    
    console.log(arr10(array1));
```

arr10(array1); should return an array with every number inside array1 * 10. I don't understand why I get undefined.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the `arr10` function.

Comment: you need to return something from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add return in function:

```js
const array1 = [2,5,10];
const arr10 = function(arr) { return arr.map(x => x * 10); };
console.log(arr10(array1));
```

Comment: thanks, helped me get over a misconception i had about functions

Answer (score 1):

The confusion might be related to the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) cases where [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) can be ommited:

```js
const arr10 = (arr) => arr.map(x => x * 10);

console.log( arr10( [1, 2, 3] ) );
```

Comment: No disagree, `arr10` is not written in arrow function form and hence there is no confusion there. OP simply missed out the `return` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything in your function:

```
const arr10 = function(arr) { return arr.map(x => x * 10); };
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't return anything in your function.

`const arr10 = function (arr) {return arr.map((x) => {return x * 10;});}`